# Using regex to extract information from a file and need help

Tags: html, regex

I have an html file that has a table of information and I'm trying to extract specific columns.  The pattern is like this with alternating "TableDarkRow" and "TableLightRow":

```
'>817338284254611</A></td><td Class='TableDarkRow' NOWRAP> 01/14/2011</td>
```

And I'm trying to extract an array of number and date pairs :

```
817338284254611
01/14/2011
```

I tried and came up with this:

```
>([0-9])+</A>(.*)NOWRAP> ?([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4})
```

But the `(.*)` is allowing the entire document to be selected between the first and last occurrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `.*` with `.*?` for non-greedy matching.

Reference: [Watch Out for The Greediness!](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one(haven't tested):

```
/[0-9\/ ]+/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `.*` with `[A-Za-z'<> \t]+'.